# Nested query in From clause syntax and performance

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, phpmyadmin

I'm having two tables: one for user information, the second for mapping some relation between users (two column table with two ids, from id to id relation)
I'm trying to find for a specific userid all his users' relations ids (inner select) and then get more info about them by joining to a table which has more info to show.

1. Given the following error:
   [image: phpMyAdmin error]
   **Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual list that corresponds to your mySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS i Limit 0,30' at line 6**
   What wrong with my query?
2. Is this query is okay in terms of performance, or there are other way to do so?

**Query:**

```
 SELECT i.*
    FROM 
        ((SELECT uc.contactId
         FROM tbl_users AS u
         JOIN tbl_users_contacts AS uc ON u.Id = uc.userId
         WHERE uc.userId =1) AS contacts_ids JOIN tbl_users AS u 
ON contacts_ids.contactId = u.Id) AS i;
```

**Edit**: Fixed to:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    ((SELECT uc.contactId
     FROM tbl_users AS u
     JOIN tbl_users_contacts AS uc ON u.Id = uc.userId
     WHERE uc.userId =1) AS contacts_ids JOIN tbl_users AS u 
ON contacts_ids.contactId = u.Id);
```

Don't know why the final As i was a problem, so I ask for question 2 mainly for this post.

Comment: So you may have both userId and contactId same in the user table ? Or what you are trying to do, show some sample data and expected result out of it.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: I have user information, name email tel, etc this is tbl_users.  
Second table says who has who as a contact on his contact list.
I want to show for specific user all his contact list information: for each contact user to get all the details (name tel email)

Comment: What are the fields of the `tbl_users_contacts` ?

Comment: userId, contactId- both int
each userId can have multiple contactId ( in different rows)of course

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

```
mysql> create table tbl_users ( iduser int,name varchar(100),email varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into tbl_users values
    -> (1,'A','a@a.com'),
    -> (2,'B','b@b.com'),
    -> (3,'C','c@c.com'),
    -> (4,'D','d@d.com'),
    -> (5,'E','e@e.com');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table contacts (iduser int, contactid int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> insert into contacts values 
    -> (1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,1),(2,5),(3,1),(3,4);

mysql> select * from tbl_users ;
+--------+------+---------+
| iduser | name | email   |
+--------+------+---------+
|      1 | A    | a@a.com |
|      2 | B    | b@b.com |
|      3 | C    | c@c.com |
|      4 | D    | d@d.com |
|      5 | E    | e@e.com |
+--------+------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from contacts ;
+--------+-----------+
| iduser | contactid |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |         2 |
|      1 |         3 |
|      1 |         5 |
|      2 |         1 |
|      2 |         5 |
|      3 |         1 |
|      3 |         4 |
+--------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now as we can see userid = 1  has 3 contacts and we can get them as

```
select u.* from tbl_users u 
join contacts c on c.contactid = u.iduser 
where c.iduser = 1 ;
```

The output will be as

```
+--------+------+---------+
| iduser | name | email   |
+--------+------+---------+
|      2 | B    | b@b.com |
|      3 | C    | c@c.com |
|      5 | E    | e@e.com |
+--------+------+---------+
```

To boost up the performance you may add the following indexes

```
alter table tbl_users add index userid_idx(iduser);
alter table contacts add index cu_idx(iduser,contactid);
```

**Change the table and column name into the query as per your need.**